# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users returns a 403 Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, microsoft-graph

I have an SPFX application deployed on SharePoint online that requires to get the users of a SharePoint site collection.

To do that I used the PNP Graph library using the JavaScript command graph.users().

This command makes a call towards https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users. However, the call returns a 403 error with the following error message: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

[image]

I have added the following permission to the package-solution.json : "group.read.all", "user.read.all". And have accepted them via the SharePoint admin center

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a special solution I have to add in order to read the users of a site collection?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the PNP Graph are requesting delegated permissions from Microsoft Graph.

The request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` is called as the logged on user. So if the user doesn't have permission, you would get this error. If you sign in as a tenant admin, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Those permissions require admin consent... a global admin must grant those scopes before they can be used.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-72

I doubt admin consent has been granted & thus, that's why you're getting the 403.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have, as stated in my initial message. 

I'll continue investigating and post the answer if I find something.